# Nuxt context in mixin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

is there a way to get the app(spa) context (to be more specific the route) in a mixin?

I have a shared function that needs to get the route params.

Thanks

Comment: `context.route` or `this.$route` will work within a mixin (depending on ssr/client)

Comment: I tried using `this.$route` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @dor272 What code did you try? How does it not work? Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: I had a function that returns a function but for some reason I wrote it in the mixin data and not methods. once I moved it to methods it works. thanks